# Algorithm, find local/global minima, function of 2 variables

Tags: algorithm, function, minimum

Let us have a function of 2 variables:

```
 z=f(x,y) = ....
```

Can you advise me any suitable method (simply algorithmizable, fast convergence) to calculate the the local extreme on some intervals or the global extreme?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you have a mathematical formula for the function? How is f defined?

Comment: If that was available, mere calculus and a closed form solution would be enough.

Comment: @duffymo Really simple expressions may represent horrendously misbehaving surfaces, and calculus only goes so far.

Comment: @ duffyno: In some cases I have, but not always. Formulas are not trivial, they can not be expressed in the explicit form. But  I am able to compute the p artial derivateves (Stirling formula is used)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might also look into [simulated annealing](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SimulatedAnnealing.html) if you like the idea of algorithms driven by ideas from thermodynamics and metallurgy.

Or perhaps you'd rather look at [genetic algorithms,](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/gads/f6636.html) because you like the current explosion of knowledge in biology.

Comment: I'd be happy to turn my downvote into an upvote if you can reasonably explain how genetic algorithms are relevant to a simple minimization of a known 2d function, and (per the original question) simply codeable and with fast convergence.

Comment: The ideas themselves are pretty easy.  They also have the nice quality of being able to find a global max or min; gradient methods can get stuck in local extrema.  As for coding, there are libraries to help with both.  What's easier than that?  But your "happy to turn" sounds less like an invitation and more like a challenge.

Comment: Maybe they are more robust to transitive states between minima than common methods?

Comment: @ninjagecko I can come up with a few dozen "simple known 2D functions" that are *so* hard to optimize that even all the world's supercomputers combined can't find their optima in your lifetime :) Really, the GA is as good a method to solve the OPs problem as any of the others proposed here. It's relatively simple and generally has fast convergence. [Differential evolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_evolution) is even simpler and often also faster.

Answer (score 6):

[**Gradient Descent**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_descent) is a wise choice for finding local minima for functions, assuming you can calculate the gradient.

Depending on the specific domain - sometimes there are other solutions as well.

For example, for [Linear-Least-Squares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_least_squares_%28mathematics%29) (which is used for regression in the field of machine learning) , you can find local (and global, the function in this case is convex) - you can use [normal equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_least_squares_%28mathematics%29#Inverting_the_matrix_of_the_normal_equations)

**EDIT:** As suggested in comments: **If you don't have any information** on the function, you might be able to use a [**hill climbing algorithm**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_climbing) where you sample the candidates where to advance (you need to take a sample because there are infinite number of directions if the function is of real numbers) - and chose the most promising one.

You can also try to **extract the derivatives numerically** using [numerical differentiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_differentiation), and use gradient descent.

Comment: @undur_gongor: Yes, as I explicitly mentioned. If you don't have this knowledge, a hill climbing algorithm can be used, where you sample the possible directions and chose the most promising one.

Comment: Sorry, apparently I had overlooked that part.

Comment: @undur_gongor: Also, I just editted and added another solution - calculate the derivatives numerically.